# Calling part of jsp page from Servlet or Java Class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need to call small part of `JSP` page(like only div load) when a method is invoked? I know we can load whole `JSP` page from `Servlet`. Is this possible or any other solution for this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: there is a method in my application which gives different responses . I want to load different jsp components on different responses . Is this possible ?

Comment: Are you using a MVC framework?

Comment: no , there is like one JSP page and one main method which is running continuously listening from server. I need to render JSP page on type of responses .

Comment: your description makes no sense.  "one main method ... continuously listening from server".  Are you attempting to server push?

Comment: this method is continuously pulling information from server. Information is not same every time . @DwB

Answer (score 0):

> know we can load whole JSP page from Servlet. Is this possible

Yes it is possible, you forward your request to jsp from servlet and it will render that jsp, [here is an exact same example](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Answer (score 0):

1) Set some session or request variable equal to some value, say `boolean myVar = true`.

2) Redirect from your `jsp` page from your servlet.

3) In the `jsp` page, check for particular condition for the variable `myVar`. If condition is fulfilled, using `scriptlets` or `JSTL` display only the relevant part of you `jsp`.

Comment: this will refresh the page and we will lose the values from the page ,say text box value will be null . How can we handle this ?

Comment: you can send those values with the request, and then redisplay them - not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX(Asynchronous Javascript and XML) for this purpose

For example, Suggestions, that appear without any refresh for auto-complete in google search, are using Ajax. JSP code will contain the Ajax code and will send the information to the servlet in form of *XmlHttpRequest* object and then takes the response from servlet as *xmlhttp.responseText*. The result can be written at JSP page by using DOM.

To initiate this process, you need to use the *onkeyup* in input tag like this:

`<input type="text" onkeyup="methodName(this.value)"`

[Learn more about Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

To use AJAX with Java, try this

[Ajax for Java Web Applications](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/ajax-quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myDiv').load('serverPage.jsp #server_div_id');
```

OR

```
$.ajax({
url: 'serverPage.jsp',
success: function(data) {
      data=$(data).find('div#id');
      $('#mydiv').html(data);       
  }
});
```